# Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, private, protected, public

Quais são as diferenças entre os modificadores `public`, `default`, `protected` e `private` quando se trabalha com herança?

Existem regras de como e quando eu devo usar eles quando eu estou trabalhando com herança e polimorfismo?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Não existe nenhuma regra, somente boas práticas. Vamos do começo.

Pra começar existem somente 3 **modificadores** (`private`, `protected` e `public`), e com isso temos 4 **níveis** de visibilidade

Os níveis são os que você disse: `private`, `default`, `protected` e `public`

**Private**:
A única classe que tem acesso ao atributo é a própria classe que o define, ou seja, se uma classe `Pessoa` declara um atributo privado chamado `nome`, somente a classe `Pessoa` terá acesso a ele.

**Default**: Tem acesso a um atributo `default` (identificado pela ausência de modificadores) todas as classes que estiverem **no mesmo pacote** que a classe que possui o atributo.

**Protected**: Esse é o que pega mais gente, ele é praticamente igual ao `default`, com a diferença de que se uma classe (mesmo que esteja fora do pacote) estende da classe com o atributo `protected`, ela terá acesso a ele. Então o acesso é por pacote e por herança.

**Public**: Esse é fácil, todos tem acesso :)

O nível de visibilidade envolve encapsulamento. É sempre dito como boa prática que atributos internos devem ser privados, pois classes externas nem devem saber que ele existe. O que a classe expõe são suas funcionalidades, sua API, se preferir. Expor atributos internos pode causar sérios problemas de segurança. Se tem algo que é inerente à implementação, que pode vir a mudar no futuro. provavelmente deve ser privado.

Comment: Boa resposta. Eu só adicionaria que existe sim uma "regra" não oficial: sempre comece com private, e vai aumentando aos poucos, dependendo da necessidade. Tudo o que você expõe a outras classes (ou seja, tudo o que não for privado) faz parte da sua API, portanto, mudanças nestes métodos e propriedades não-privados (especialmente públicos) podem trazer consequências aos consumidores.

Comment: Vale adicionar a essa resposta que não apenas atributos são qualificados com esses modificadores, mas também métodos. Uma boa prática é utilizar para o modificador _private_ nos atributos, uma vez que se tratam de dados internos. Se precisarem ser acessados externamente, o uso de métodos de acesso (_getters_ e _setters_) mantém o controle da classe (para validação, por exemplo). Para os métodos que não devem ser acessados externamente, deve-se procurar utilizar _protected_. Assim eles podem ser sobrescritos se necessário, não poluem o IntelliSense dos editores e ajudam na organização.

Comment: E também é importante lembrar que métodos e atributos protected no java tem exposição pública para todas as classes que estão no mesmo pacote, independente de serem subclasses ou não.

Comment: Excelente observação @bWowk, faz toda diferença isso que você falou. Deveria ser adicionado à resposta oficial.

Comment: @bWowk, @Marcelo Rodovalho mas foi isso que eu quis dizer quando falei que ele é praticamente igual ao `default`, e expliquei a diferença entre eles.

Answer (score 37):

Traduzindo uma ótima resposta do SO em inglês, do David Segonds:

Esse [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) pode ser de alguma ajuda pra você.

```
 Modifier      Class   Package   Subclass   World
──────────────────────────────────────────────────
 public          ✔        ✔         ✔         ✔

 protected       ✔        ✔         ✔         ✘

 no modifier     ✔        ✔         ✘         ✘

 private         ✔        ✘         ✘         ✘
──────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

E um comentário importante feito para essa resposta (Edd):

> Provavelmente é útil deixar claro que em caso de não haver modificador, a subclasse poder ou não acessar os métodos/atributos da sua superclasse depende da localização da subclasse. Se a subclasse estiver em um pacote diferente do pacote da superclasse, a resposta é que ela não poderá acessar. Porém, ela poderá acessá-los caso esteja no mesmo pacote da superclasse.

Link para o original [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Answer (score 17):

Esses modificadores são responsáveis pelo **controle de acesso** aos membros da classe (campos e métodos), também conhecido como **encapsulamento**. A ideia é auxiliar na criação de uma API estável, mas ao mesmo dar margem para que o código mude no futuro (em outras palavras, separar bem o que é especificação do que é implementação).

As virtudes do encapsulamento são discutíveis, existem linguagens que se viram bem sem nenhum controle de acesso (i.e. todo o código consegue acessar qualquer coisa), mas de todo modo a redução no [acoplamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) dos diversos componentes de um sistema é um objetivo desejável (maior facilidade de evolução, e potencialmente menos bugs). Em especial projetos desenvolvidos por equipes numerosas e/ou pouco experientes, não é bom expor demais código que não é pra ser mexido (ou simplesmente acessado) por outros que não os responsáveis por determinada funcionalidade. No restante dessa resposta, vou assumir esse tipo de cenário, outros - por exemplo, projetos desenvolvidos por uma pessoa só - talvez se beneficiem de um controle de acesso mais "relaxado".

As demais respostas já dão uma boa visão geral. Vou abordar cada modificador com um pouco mais de detalhe:

## `private`

Os membros privados são aqueles campos e métodos que dizem respeito somente à implementação da classe, e que não interessam a quem vai usá-la. Decidir o que interessa ou não pode ser difícil, mas algumas perguntas podem ajudar a guiar o processo de decisão:

- Esse membro faz parte do contrato da classe? Se faz, não pode ser privado...
- Se alguém usar "errado" esse membro (alterar valores do campo, chamar o método na hora errada ou com os parâmetros errados, etc) as consequências serão negativas e/ou imprevisíveis? Se sim, é um bom candidato a ser privado.
- Você pretende alterar esse membro no futuro? Tem uma ideia melhor de implementação que ainda não pode por em prática, ou não está 100% seguro que é assim mesmo que as coisas tem que ser? Colocar como privado te dá mais liberdade pra alterar no futuro, ainda que tenha muita gente utilizando sua classe.

Há quem recomende que todos os campos sejam privados, e isso é um bom *começo* quando se está a projetar uma classe. No futuro, se mudar de ideia pode aumentar a exposição de um membro privado à vontade, mas *diminuir* a exposição em geral causa problemas (potencialmente quebrando o código que usa sua classe). Por isso eu diria que, na dúvida, torne tudo privado...

## `public`

Os membros públicos são aqueles campos e métodos que fazem parte do contrato da classe. Se a classe representa um **tipo** (seja uma implementação concreta de um tipo já existente, ou um subtipo de outro), seu contrato é a API que os consumidores têm à disposição para usar a classe.

Após uma classe ser disponibilizada, ou publicada, deve-se assumir que qualquer membro público da mesma pode estar sendo usada por outros códigos, fora do seu controle. Assim, é importante *jamais* alterar/remover um membro público durante todo o ciclo de vida do produto, dentro das versões onde se espera [compatibilidade reversa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibilidade_reversa) (*backward compatibility*). Se necessário marcar certo membro como obsoleto (`deprecated`), ainda assim é desejável dar manutenção apropriada a ele - certificando-se que mantenha-se funcionando nas novas versões e com o comportamento esperado de acordo com a época que foi escrito (em certas situações limitadas, até com os mesmos bugs).

Ao decidir o que tornar público, veja tudo o que é necessário (pelas classes herdadas e interfaces implementadas, por exemplo) e acrescente o que considera útil (em casos e uso razoáveis). Deixe de fora todo o resto. Em particular, se acha que certa parte do código terá de ser mexida no futuro, não coloque ela pública a menos que extremamente necessário.

## `protected`

Sua principal finalidade é auxiliar no processo de extensão (herança) da classe. Em princípio, um campo/método `protected` poderia muito bem ser privado: ele trata de detalhes de implementação, mas não do contrato da classe. Entretanto, ainda que tais detalhes não sejam relevantes a quem usa a classe, podem o ser para quem tenta criar subtipos da mesma (já que os subtipos compartilham boa parte da implementação, e portanto se interessam sim pelos detalhes).

Enquanto campos privados não fazem parte de qualquer contrato - e portanto podem ser alterados a bel prazer do programador em versões futuras da classe - tanto os campos públicos quanto os protegidos devem idealmente possuir uma API estável. É claro que você pode tornar um ou outro obsoleto se necessário (é pra isso que o `deprecated` existe), mas é preciso ter consciência que isso pode quebrar código que os utiliza. Assim, caso decida expor detalhes de implementação para subclasses, certifique-se que esses detalhes são *estáveis*, que é improvável que os mesmos venham a ser alterados no futuro.

## "padrão" (*default*) ou "pacote" (*package-protected*)

Esse modificador (expresso pela ausência dos outros três modificadores) é um caso meio "estranho": outras classes dentro do mesmo pacote podem acessar os campos padrão, mas o restante do código não. É difícil determinar a serventia exata do mesmo, mas eu penso que ele auxilia a evolução do sistema:

Quando se começa a escrever um programa, nem sempre dá pra antecipar exatamente o que é estável e o que não é, o que deve ir pra API e o que não deve. O programa não está estruturado de forma ideal, e as classes acessam membros umas das outras que não deveriam. Isso não devia acontecer, mas acontece, e *nesse momento do desenvolvimento* isso não é um grande problema - afinal de contas o código ainda não foi disponibilizado, somente o autor tem acesso a ele, e espera-se que ele tenha cuidado para não fazer mal uso das classes que ele mesmo escreveu...

Forçar o programador a escolher um nível de acesso logo de cara, antes mesmo dele "sentir" o que o código deve ou não fazer, me parece contraproducente. Mesmo após certo nível de estabilidade, espera-se que quem escreveu um conjunto de códigos (os pacotes são normalmente feitos pelos mesmos autores, ou no mínimo pela mesma organização) cometam menos erros e/ou sejam capazes de alterar seus componentes sempre que um deles mudar e afetar negativamente os outros.

Sendo assim, eu diria para usá-lo "sempre que estiver na dúvida", mas se livrar dele assim que conseguir determinar o melhor modificador a se usar. Com a experiência, o uso do *default* fica mais e mais raro, até chegar o ponto que ele não é necessário em absoluto.

Comment: O que você quer dizer por "contrato da classe"?

Comment: @GuilhermeUmemura o conceito vem daqui: [Programação por Contrato](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_por_contrato). Se tiver dúvida, sugiro abrir uma pergunta separada sobre isso, eu já não participo deste site faz tempo, mas outros podem dar uma boa resposta (já que é um tópico comum em OO).

Answer (score 8):

Suponha que você tem uma classe `Animal` e uma subclasse `Gato`, que herda de `Animal`.

Na classe `Gato`, você poderá chamar todos os métodos de `Animal` declarados como `public` ou `protected`, e se as classes estiverem no mesmo pacote, os métodos default. Ou seja, `Gato` não chama os métodos `private` de `Animal`. O mesmo raciocínio se aplica a atributos.

Você também pode sobrescrever (override), em `Gato`, os métodos `public` e `protected` de `Animal` e, se estiver no mesmo pacote, também os métodos default.

Note que você pode ter, em `Gato`, um método com a mesma assinatura de um método `private` de `Animal`, mas nesse caso trata-se de um método novo, e não uma nova versão do método de `Animal`. Isso fica claro nesse exemplo:

```java
class Animal {
  protected void metodoProtected() {
    System.out.println("animal protected");
  }
  private void metodoPrivate() {
    System.out.println("animal private");
  }
}

class Gato extends Animal {
  protected void metodoProtected() {
    System.out.println("gato protected");
  }
  private void metodoPrivate() {
    System.out.println("gato private");
  }
}
```

Agora, se você tiver uma referência do tipo `Animal` para um objeto do tipo `Gato`, e chamar:

```java
Animal animal = new Gato();
animal.metodoProtected();
animal.metodoPrivate();
```

O resultado será

```
gato protected
animal private
```

Como o método private de `Animal` não foi sobrescrito por `Gato`, é ele que é chamado quando você tem uma referência do tipo `Animal`.

Boas práticas:

- se o método deve ser usado por outras classes (que não são subclasses), use `public`;
- caso contrário, se você quer que suas subclasses possam alterar algum comportamento, encapsule o comportamento em um método `protected`;
- se o método trata de um detalhe de implementação e você não quer que ninguém modifique (nem mesmo as subclasses), use `private`.