# Qual a finalidade do modificar de acesso protected em Java? Em que situações devo utilizá-lo?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

Em relação aos modificadores de acesso em Java, qual a finalidade do modificador **protected**? Qual a sua finalidade na prática?

Comment: É, agora que vi o link.

Answer (score 1):

> **Default:** Tem acesso a um atributo default (identificado pela ausência de modificadores) todas as classes que estiverem no mesmo pacote que a classe que possui o atributo.
>
> **Protected:** Esse é o que pega mais gente, ele é praticamente igual ao default, com a diferença de que se uma classe (mesmo que esteja fora do pacote) estende da classe com o atributo protected, ela terá acesso a ele. Então o acesso é por pacote e por herança.

Autor: @rodrigo-sasaki

Link: [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private)

---

**Caso de uso**

**Em uma classe:** Utilize o em uma classe quando quiser esconde-la de pacotes diferentes do seu atual e de filhos do seu pacote.

**Em um atributo:** Quando existir a necessidade de obter diretamente o atributo "sem o uso de getters e setters" por classes que estão no mesmo pacote, ou que herdam da atual classe.

**Em um método:** Utilize quando for necessário proteger seu método de acessos de fora do seu pacote ou de classes que não herdem o comportamento.