# Melhores práticas quanto ao uso de modificadores de acesso

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern

Como restringir outras classes de acessar certos membros (**métodos, variáveis/campos, classes/interfaces aninhadas**) de uma classe?

Gostaria de saber quais as melhores práticas para se usar os modificadores de acesso dos membros de uma class. Com isso saber a combinação correta de modificadores de acesso e as entidades (classes, interfaces, enums, métodos e variáveis) a que podem ser aplicadas.

E saber as implicações de modificar o modificador de acesso de uma entidade Java na prática e uso do dia-a-dia, não apenas os conceitos dos modificador tal como na pergunta [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23/6789)

Comment: Você se refere à utilização de `private` ou procura alguma coisa mais complexa?

Comment: [leonardopessoa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57474/leonardopessoa), isso mesmo ... eu gostaria de saber quais as melhores práticas para se usar os modificadores de acesso dos membros de uma class.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private)

Comment: [diegofm](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/28595/diegofm), acredito que não seja duplicata ... porque pretendo aprender formas diferentes de usar .... não comparar. A minha pergunta é para uso empírico ... uso prático, não apenas conceitual, Entende?

Comment: @pss1suporte bom, de qualquer forma, é bom que esta fica relacionada com a outra, para pesquisas =)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private)

Comment: @diegofm, sim ... tem relação sim. Agora que li as respostas, vi que é bom ficar relacionadas. Obrigado por contribuir e editar os títulos. Estou aprendendo e vou aprendendo ..... Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você já deve saber, existem 4 tipos de visibilidade em java:

- `public`
- `private`
- `protected`
- *package-default* (isso não é uma palavra-chave, é o que acontece quando nenhum modificador é usado).

Em projetos de software maduros e bem-projetados, o `protected` e o *package-default* quase nunca são usados:

- No caso do `protected`, a herança tem sido visto como algo ruim de alguns anos para cá. O motivo é que a herança introduz um acoplamento forte da subclasse para a superclasse. Quando você usa campos ou métodos `protected` e a superclasse depende deles serem utilizados de determinadas formas pelas subclasses, você também acaba acoplando a superclasse às suas subclasses. Isso vai na contramão das boas práticas de projeto de sistemas orientado a objetos que prezam o fraco acoplamento. Com o uso de padrões de projeto, é possível eliminar-se todos os casos de herança e trocá-los por composição exceto quando você tem que usar bibliotecas de terceiros que não podem ser modificadas e que fornecem superclasses que impõem herança para serem usadas.
- No caso do *package-default*, se uma classe precisa expôr funcionalidades seletivamente para outras classes no mesmo pacote, mas não para as demais classes, é sinal de que existe algum problema de [coesão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)), [acoplamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) ou de [encapsulamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

Assim sendo, a menos que você esteja usando alguma biblioteca que te imponha restrições draconianas, em um projeto bem feito, quase não vão existir casos onde seja boa ideia usar `protected` ou *package-default*. Onde elas ocorrerem e forem de fato a melhor alternativa, provavelmente vai ser para contornar alguma limitação da linguagem. Portanto, vamos focar no `public` e no `private`:

No caso de campos/atributos que não tenham ambos os modificadores `static` e `final`, o modificador correto é o `private` e ponto final. Se você está tentado a usar qualquer coisa que não seja `private` em um atributo não-`static` ou não-`final` (inclusive esquecer-se de colocar o `private`), você está fazendo alguma coisa errada.

Os campos que forem simultaneamente `static` e `final` podem ser públicos desde que sejam referentes a valores de tipos primitivos ou objetos imutáveis. Mesmo quando privados, ainda assim é boa ideia que tratem-se de valores primitivos ou objetos imutáveis.

Uma classe deve publicar para outras, uma API (conjunto de campos, métodos, construtores e classes internas) que detalha quais são as funcionalidades que ela oferece às outras classes para ser usada. As partes da classe que estão nessa API que ela oferece às outras recebem o modificador `public`, e o que estiver fora deste conjunto, deve ficar com o `private`. Um método que representa uma funcionalidade completa e importante da regra de negócio da classe provavelmente deve ser `public`. Algo que representa um trecho de código que estava em um método qualquer e que foi separado em um novo método a parte apenas para ficar melhor organizado, provavelmente deve ser `private`.

Para os métodos, construtores e classes internas, você tem que julgar se aquilo é alguma coisa que interessa a outras classes ou não. A classe deve ser feita procurando prezar-se pelo encapsulamento, alta coesão e baixo acoplamento, o que vai ajudar a separar aquilo que ela oferece ao mundo daquilo que é apenas um detalhe técnico interno da forma como ele é implementada. Esse julgamento é subjetivo e requer uma boa dose de experiência para ser feito corretamente, mas na maioria das vezes, julgar qual é o melhor caso é fácil, embora existam sempre alguns que estão na zona cinzenta.

A partir do Java 8, interfaces podem ter métodos estáticos e com implementações padrão (não confundir o modificador `default` empregado com a visibilidade *package-default*, não é essa a finalidade do modificador). Isso ajuda a reduzir a necessidade de se usar o `protected` e o *package-private*. Alie isso com os lambdas, e essa necessidade se reduz ainda mais.

Até o Java 8, tudo que fosse colocado dentro de uma `interface` era `public`, mesmo se a palavra-chave `public` não estiver lá (se você não colocar o modificador `public` em um método de uma `interface`, o compilador vai fingir que o modificador estava lá, não existe *package-default* para membros de interface). A partir do Java 9, interfaces podem ter métodos privados também (que devem ter o modificador `private`) e que não são herdados pelas classes que implementam essa interface. Essa mudança no Java 9 serve para eliminar um dos já pouquíssimos casos onde a visibilidade *package-default* fazia sentido, que era o de prover (por meio de classes auxiliares no mesmo pacote) funcionalidades com implementações aos métodos `default` ou `static` da interface que não deveriam ser herdados.

Answer (score -1):

Encapsulando e deixando os atributos como **Protected** exemplo:

***protected String nome;***

Permitindo que somente os **métodos** das classes herdeiras efetuem acesso e manipulação dos atributos.

Se deixarmos **Private** exemplo: **Private String nome;** somente os métodos da mesma classe, podem efetuar alterações, e se deixarmos **Public** todos os métodos independente da classe, podem efetuar alterações.

Em suma.

**protected** além de manter a segurança dos atributos, ele só permite que os métodos de sua classe, e os métodos das classes herdeiras efetuem alterações...

Comment: Limitadores de acesso não servem para manter a "segurança dos atributos". Servem para manter a interface de uma classe, assim como sua encapsulação, consistente. Não se deve usar restritores de acesso indiscriminadamente. Deve-se expor o mínimo de informações possíveis a respeito de um módulo.