# modificador static em um atributo

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou querendo saber se o modificador static precisa necessariamente estar no mesmo pacote que as outras classes no meu projeto.

Exemplo: tenho uma classe chamada usuário dentro do pacote utilizadores e uma outra classe chamada valoresConstantes dentro do pacote MetodosUteis. O problema é que não estou conseguindo chamar a variável estática VALORCONSTANTE da classe de mesmo nome na classe Usuarios.

Comment: Está ocorrendo algum error, poderia dar mais alguns detalhes? Ou código de como você está tentando acessar a constante? Pode ser uma linha

Comment: não, erro algum, na verdade é só uma duvida que tenho. Eu costumo contornar ela usando métodos get para me retornar o valor

Comment: static nao tem a ver com visibilidade, e sim, se a variavel somente existirá quando houver uma instancia ou se ela existira independente disso. O que define visibilidade sao os modificadores private, public e quando está sem modificador, que é a visibilidade packet.

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23/28595)

Comment: Relacionada: [Melhores práticas quanto ao uso de modificadores de acesso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194043/28595)

Comment: então se ela estiver com o modificador public em outro pacote eu ainda terei acesso ao valor que ela contém?

Comment: bota um código @AlexSusama, as vezes é algo simples

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Stuff {
    public final static String NAME = "I'm a static variable";
}
```

E em outro pacote, desde que foi realizado corretamente o import

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Stuff.NAME);
    }

}
```

Exemplo e Fonte: https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they.html