# Qual a melhor maneira de definir o acesso aos métodos de uma classe que quero usar para testes unitários?

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, junit

Eu tenho uma classe `Runnable`, que faz um monte de coisas no meu sistema. Quando eu criei ela, eu não queria instanciar os métodos dela fora do escopo dela. Por isso eu escrevi os métodos como `protected`.

Agora, eu estou querendo escrever alguns testes unitários pra essa classe, eu pensei em 2 soluções:

> 1 - Deixar o método público.
>
> 2 - Fazer a classe de teste `extends` a classe em questão para usar da funcionalidade do `protected`.

**Qual seria a melhor solução?**

Gostaria de mencionar também que estou guardando meus testes em um *package* diferente de onde está a classe que quero testar.

```
public class QualityTest extends DailyJob {

    @Test
    public void testGetBaseById() {
        /*
            testa se o metodo getBasePeloId está retornando um objeto do tipo base, como deveria.
         */
        Base realBase = getBaseById(1);
        assertTrue(realBase instanceof Base);
    }
}
```

O `DailyJob` se encontra no package `BackgroundProcesses`.

O `QualityTest` se encontra no package `UnitTests`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro vou falar um pouquinho sobre herança. Herança não serve para a escrita de testes. Não use herança para isso. Aliás, há pessoas que defendem, inclusive eu, que herança não deveria ser usada para nada, devendo ser sempre que possível substituída por composição ou por alguma outra coisa com o objetivo de atingir-se um acoplamento mais fraco e uma coesão mais alta, que são objetivos opostos aos promovidos pelo uso de herança. Falo um pouco disso [no meio dessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276869/132). Falo algo nesse sentido também [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260943/132), onde também abordo o `protected`.

Dentro do seu teste de unidade, você instancia a classe que você quer testar ou obtém uma instância dela por meio de uma factory, singleton ou coisa assim e a utiliza. O que importa é saber essa regra número 1:

> (1) o teste **usa** o objeto a ser testado.

No entanto a herança estabelece essa relação:

> (2) uma instância da subclasse **é um** objeto do tipo da superclasse.

Se você usar herança no seu teste, estará estabelecendo que o teste **é um** objeto a ser testado ao invés do teste **usar** o objeto a ser testado. Dessa forma, se você utilizar a sua segunda alternativa, estará violando a regra 1 acima. Logo, não use herança.

Seu teste seria algo assim:

```
public class QualityTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetBaseById() {
        /*
            testa se o método getBasePeloId está retornando
            um objeto do tipo base, como deveria.
         */
        DailyJob d = new DailyJob();
        Base realBase = d.getBaseById(1);
        assertTrue(realBase instanceof Base);
    }
}
```

Comment: Legal Victor, com as respostas extras que você linkou ali, todas minhas duvidas foram sanadas. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa deixar o seu método público para conseguir testá-lo. O ideal é que somente os métodos públicos sejam testados. Se o seu método é privado, significa que algum método público irá chamá-lo. Você consegue realizar os testes através do método público.

Por exemplo, imagine que essa é a sua classe `Base`:

```
public class Base {

    public int getNumero() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

E essa é a sua classe `DailyJob`:

```
public class DailyJob {

    private Base getBaseId(int i) {
        return new Base();
    }

    public int calculo(int i) {
        Base base = getBaseId(i);
        return  base.getNumero() + 1;
    }
}
```

Você consegue perfeitamente realizar seu teste através do método `calculo`. Seu teste seria:

```
@Test
public void testCalculo() {
    DailyJob d = new DailyJob();
    int resultado = d.calculo(1);
    int valorEsperado = 3;
    assertEquals(resultado, valorEsperado);
}
```

Se o método for complexo e for realmente necessário criar um teste só para ele, uma estratégia é deixar a acessibilidade `package`. Contudo, a classe de teste precisa estar no mesmo pacote da classe a ser testada. Vale ressaltar que independente disso, é interessante que as classes de testes sempre fiquem no mesmo pacote da classe que está sendo testada.

Se você estiver utilizando algum gerenciador de build como Maven ou Gradle, eles fazem uma separação de pastas para os códigos e resources que devem ir para produção e os códigos e resources que são apenas para teste.

Tanto o maven quanto o gradle utilizam `src/main/java` como diretório para produção e `src/test/java` como diretório para testes. Você pode replicar os pacotes nas duas pastas, mas ambas não serão consideradas como pacotes, apenas o que estiver abaixo delas.

Veja imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que `DailyJob` está em `src/main/java` e `DailyJobTest` está em `src/test/java`. Apesar disso, as duas estão dentro do mesmo pacote `stackoverflow.dailyJobPackage`. Sendo assim você conseguirá acessar os métodos tranquilamente e eles continuarão invisíveis para as classes dos outros pacotes. Quando o projeto for compilado o gerenciador de build utilizará apenas o que está em `src/main/java` para fazer o build.

Sem utilizar um gerenciador de build é possível alcançar o mesmo resultado, mas você terá que fazer a configuração.

Comment: Muito boa resposta Fagner! Fiquei na duvida "src/main/java" e "src/test/java" estão de baixo da source folder "src"?  Não entendi como eles estão em baixo do mesmo package

Comment: Ambos estão no pacote `stackoverflow.dailyJobPackage`, é esse que conta.

Comment: @user94991 Atualizei a resposta para explicar essa questão das pastas.