# erro na compilação java ( javac )

Tags: java, compilação

tenho um arquivo "poo1.java":

```
package pootest;

public class init{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Caneta bic1 = new Caneta();
                bic1.cor = "azul";
                bic1.tampada = true;
                bic1.ponta = 0.5f;
                bic1.carga = 45;
                bic1.modelo = "comun";
                bic1.rabiscar();
        }
}
```

e um outro arquivo "caneta.java":

```
package pootest;

class Caneta{
        String modelo;
        String cor;
        float ponta;
        int carga;
        boolean tampada = true;

        void tampar(boolean estado){
                tampada = estado;
        }

        void rabiscar(){
                if (tampada){
                        System.out.print("ta tampada seu jumnet$
                } else{
                        System.out.print("boiolage");
                }
        }
}
```

e quando eu compilo o poo1.java( javac poo1.java ) no terminal essa é a saída:

> poo1.java:3: error: class init is public, should be declared in a file
>   named init.java public class init{
>          ^ poo1.java:5: error: cannot find symbol       Caneta bic1 = new Caneta();         ^   symbol:   class Caneta   location: class init
>   poo1.java:5: error: cannot find symbol        Caneta bic1 = new Caneta();
>                           ^   symbol:   class Caneta   location: class init 3 errors

Comment: Cade a saida do terminal?

Comment: desculpa eu achava que tinha colocado...

Comment: valeu ta funcionando

Answer (score 3):

Além do fato de você não fechar a string e nem o parenteses do `println`, não finalizar a linha com `;`, e não utilizar modificadores de acesso, o erro provavelmente é devido ao fato de você nomear o arquivo como `poo1.java` e escrever a classe com o nome de `init`.

Em java, o nome da classe principal **DEVE** ser o mesmo nome do arquivo. É permitido classes internas no mesmo arquivo, mas a classe principal sempre deve ter o mesmo nome do arquivo.

Outro problema é o fato de não seguir as [convenções do java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/28595) e escrever classes toda a minúscula. Fique atento a isso, pois seguir essas regras é essencial pra escrever um código que seja legível não só apenas por você.

Links recomendados para leitura:

- [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23/28595)
- [Melhores práticas quanto ao uso de modificadores de acesso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194043/28595)

Comment: Qual o motivo do negativo? Se você realmente se importa com qualidade, me informe o que tem de errado para que eu possa melhorar. Negativar e ficar em silencio você não está ajudando em nada o site e nem a mim.