# Modificadores de acesso no TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Em uma aplicação que utilize TypeScript, qual a necessidade de utilizar modificadores de acesso? Pois em tempo de execução os modificadores não fazem sentido para o Javascript.

Comment: Você sabe o que os modificadores de acesso fazem no geral? Eles costumam ser iguais entre as linguagens. Veja em [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23/5878) e [Melhores práticas quanto ao uso de modificadores de acesso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194043/5878). TypeScript funciona da mesma forma, então não se assuste se for fechada como duplicada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss após a transpilação esses conceitos não fazem sentido

Comment: Então isso seria um "sim" para a minha pergunta de que você sabe o que cada um faz, correto?

Comment: @renanzin, os features adicionados pelo TypeScript existem para oferecer uma abstração a mais para permitir que o programador tenha habilidade de impor algumas restrições ao seu código de modo que o compilador já acuse erros na hora da transpilação, minimizando a necessidade da tarefa tediosa de debugar Javascript.