# Alguém pode me da uma noção de como faço

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Modele computacionalmente a representação do funcionamento de uma
lâmpada, em que é possível acender, apagar e verificar se a lâmpada está
acessa.

Fiz isto:

```
class Lampada {


  boolean aceso = true;


  void apaga() {
    aceso = false; 
  }


  void acende() {
    aceso = true; 
  }


  boolean estaApagada() {
    if (aceso == false) {
      return true;
    }
    else { 
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Pelo código que você mostrou agora, parece feito. Não?

Comment: Uma lampada já começa acesa? Ta certo isso mesmo?

Comment: O método `estaApagada()` pode ser resumida a apenas uma linha: `return !aceso;`

Comment: O enunciado diz "verificar se a lâmpada está acesa", esse método está verificando se a lampada está apagada: `estaApagada()`, me parece meio incoerente embora funcione.

Answer (score 2):

A classe parece pronta, mas uma melhoria pode ser feita no método `estaApagada()`:

```
  boolean estaApagada() {
    return !aceso;
  }
```

Isso retornará o oposto da variável aceso, que é exatamente o status esperado pelo método.

Há outras coisas que podem ser melhoradas, como o fato de você não definir uma visibilidade mais restrita a variavel `aceso`. Ora se ela precisa de dois métodos para que seja alterada, não convem deixá-la com um possivel acesso externo, adicionando `private` você restringe o acessi direto a ela.

Outro detalhe citado pelo [@Douglas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235141/algu%C3%A9m-pode-me-da-uma-no%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-como-fa%C3%A7o#comment481452_235141) e que faz total sentido é o enunciado pedir para que seja verificado se a lampada está acesa, e seu método verifica se está apagada. Embora também seja possível fazer essa verificação com o método criado, o método parece incoerente em relação ao solicitado no enunciado. A correção é tão simples quanto o método atual, basta retornar a própria variavel `aceso`.

A classe com as sugestões aplicadas ficaria assim:

```
class Lampada {

    private boolean aceso = true;

    public void apaga() {
       aceso = false; 
    }

    public void acende() {
        aceso = true; 
    }

    public boolean estaAceso(){

        return aceso;
    }
}
```

---

Deixo abaixo alguns links aqui do proprio site que podem te ajudar a aprender mais sobre conceitos basicos do java e de orientação a objeto:

[Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23/28595)

[O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81314/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-conceitos-de--e-acoplamento)

[Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13372/programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-funcional-e-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-a-objetos-o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-quais-suas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Como você mesmo apontou, também é estranho a lâmpada começar acesa. Aliás essa verificação se está apagada também é estranha. Se a propriedade é `aceso`, a pergunta mais natural (na minha cabeça) seria `boolean estaAcesa`, que retornaria `aceso`, que por sua vez seria `private`. Enfim, se quiser mexer no código tem muita coisa, mas a pergunta não é nada clara sobre o que quer.

Comment: @bfavaretto pensei nessas coisas, mas tinha achado que, pela falta de clareza, não seria necessario comentar, mas tem razão, por parecer se tratar de um iniciante, é bom citar esses problemas.

Comment: Pois é, meu comentário lá em cima ("... parece feito. Não?") era meio pra ver se ele diz onde quer chegar. Mas não disse...