# O uso de "private" em classes no C# é opcional?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, private

Qual a diferença entre `private string abc = "";` e `string abc = "";`?
Tem alguma diferença ou é só a forma de escrever que muda?

Eu fiz um teste com e sem o private e não vi diferença, funcionou igualmente.

Exemplo:

```
public class c {
   string texto = "";
}
```

e

```
public class c {
    private string texto = "";
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private)

Comment: Pessoal creio que a pergunta não é duplicata, depois que li melhor a pergunta entendi o enunciado, aproveitei e editei o titulo para evitar confusões.

Comment: Se você não coloca nada, o compilador coloca o private pra você. Ou seja, da na mesma.

Comment: @isaque não há motivos para se aborrecer com isso, somos humanos, todos erramos, até os mais experientes do site tem esse direito, não somos máquinas, basta chegar e conversar, fora que não só quem fechou falhou, você também poderia ter feito um titulo melhor/intuitivo. Quem fechou errou, quem criou a pergunta errou, todos erraram, o que importa é chegar e conversar e no seu caso editar para esclarecer melhor. Conversando todos chegaremos a um bom resultado. Se ninguem reabrir a pergunta vc pode solicitar ajuda no https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento De boa! (-:

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Não sei se está claro pra você o que esse modificador faz. Recomendo a leitura de [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private/34#34), que te indicaram nos comentários. Lá explica bem. Basicamente, declarando `private`, sua propriedade ou método não é vista ou modificada de fora da classe onde ela está declarada. Como `public`, ela pode ser vista de fora. Como `protected`, só pode ser vista de objetos que herdam da classe atual.

Sobre não usar nenhum modificador de acesso, como no seu exemplo: no C# isso é [equivalente a declarar como `private`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) (no caso de propriedades ou métodos):

> The access level for class members and struct members, including nested classes and structs, is private by default.
>   (*O nível de acesso para membros de classes e structs, incluindo classes e structs aninhados, é `private` por padrão*.)

Ou seja, dá na mesma. Como regra geral, se você não indica que tipo de acesso o membro pode ter, será considerado o mais restritivo possível. Porém, isso pode não ficar claro para quem estiver lendo o seu código. Pensando nisso, recomenda-se sempre usar explicitamente o modificador de acesso.

Comment: Só um detalhe: o modificador de acesso padrão é `private` para membros de tipos, mas para tipos em si é `internal`.

Answer (score 17):

De fato usar `private` ou omití-lo **não tem diferença prática** alguma, já que o [modificador padrão de classes e estruturas no C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) é o privado.

O uso explícito da keyword `private` denota a intenção de usar o modificador de acesso com mais clareza.

```
private String texto = "";
```

O trecho acima pode parecer redundante porém isso ajuda o leitor do seu código entendê-lo com maior intelecção e facilidade. Quem lerá seu código pode programar em outras linguagens que tem outros padrões de modificadores de acesso e por aí vai.

Isso tudo de deixar as coisas explícitas não se limitam muito à linguagem. No ["The Zen Of Python"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), uma coleção de princípios da programação Python, é definido:

> Explicit is better than implicit. (explícito é melhor que implícito)

Outro ponto é você ter um padrão de escrita de código no seu projeto, criando ou adotando convenções.

Answer (score 16):

Só complementando as respostas que estão corretas e já respondem bem o que foi perguntado, ao contrário do que muita gente imagina, os tipos, ou seja, classes, estruturas, delegados, enumerações, etc. são internas (`internal`) por padrão.

Há discussões se este deveria ser o padrão ou até mesmo se deveria haver um padrão. O fato é que foi adotado assim.

Só cuidado com a consideração de que funcionar indica que está certo. Fez bem em perguntar para ver se não foi apenas uma coincidência.

Answer (score 3):

O uso de uma classe privada faz sentido se ela for uma classe interna de outra classe, i.e.:

```
public class Palmeiras
{
    public int mundiais
    {
        get
        {
            return Palmeiras.Mundial.Contador;
        }
    }

    private class Mundial
    {
        private static int Contador = 0;
    }
}
```

Note que enquanto `Palmeiras` é uma classe pública, a classe `Mundial` dentro dela é privada. Portanto, para qualquer outra classe, esse `Mundial` praticamente não existe.

Brincadeiras a parte, existem cenários nos quais ter uma classe mais interna que ninguém mais pode acessar pode ser útil. Por exemplo, suponha que você deve escrever uma classe para serializar arquivos. Você pode encapsular o arquivo em uma segunda classe que implementa IDisposable, e como somente a classe serializadora deve utilizar a classe de arquivos, você pode escrever a classe de arquivos dentro da classe serializadora e privada. Assim você garante que a classe mais interna somente será utilizada por quem deve ser utilizada.

Comment: Ficaria melhor ainda se Contador fosse uma constante