# Verificando se uma string é vazia no JavaScript. Idiomático ou legível?

Tags: javascript, string, convenções

Entendo que muitas vezes é melhor prezar pela legibilidade e clareza do código programando de maneira **explícita**. Isso não se detém somente ao JavaScript, também ao [C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236762/41056), [Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) e talvez ao resto das linguagens de programação.

Sei que essas convenções [não são regras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/41056), porém elas ajudam no processo de desenvolvimento caso sejam escolhidas no momento certo, no ambiente certo e de forma correta.

No JavaScript para testar se uma string é vazia ou não, pode-se utilizar:

```
const value = '';
if(!value) {
    console.log('String vazia!');
}
```

Isso acontece porque a string vazia é um valor definido como *falsy* ([documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)). E além de comparar `value` com `""`, ele compara com `null` e vários outros valores.

Embora funcione, essa forma não prejudica a legibilidade? Não é claro para um desenvolvedor C# ou Java que esse `if` seja a condição de uma string vazia.

Nesse caso, comparar de maneira explícita prejudicaria um código idiomático JavaScript, por quê?

Comment: Acredito que pode prejudicar a legibilidade porque a verificação não é exatamente se não é uma *string* vazia, mas sim se o valor é *falsy*, como bem comentou, então a leitura não é exata para quem conhece como funciona a linguagem de tipagem dinâmica. Por exemplo, se `value` for 2, o `if` será falso, mesmo que não seja uma *string* vazia. Lembrando que o JavaScript possui a [comparação frouxa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215652/5878), a verificação de *string* vazia seria `if (value === "")`. Se prejudicar a leitura, é devido a condição não fazer exatamente o descrito. Faz sentido?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se a intenção é realmente **verificar se a *string* é vazia**, então, sim, **prejudica a leitura do código** e, possivelmente, a execução do mesmo. O motivo é que a comparação feita em:

```
if (!value) {
    console.log("String vazia");
}
```

não é uma verificação se a *string* é vazia, mas sim se o valor de `value` é *falsy*, como comentado na própria pergunta. Isso implica que `value`, além de não poder ser uma *string* vazia, não poderá ser o inteiro zero, falso, nulo, indefinido, NaN (*not a number*), etc. Porém, todos estes valores seriam esperados que passassem no teste "não é uma *string* vazia", pois não são, de fato, uma *string* vazia (exceto a *string* vazia propriamente dita). Quando faço `if (!value)`, entenda-se que `value` pode ser qualquer valor *truthy* e não somente uma *string* não vazia.

```js
const testes = ["", false, null, undefined, NaN, [], 0, "Foo"];

for (let teste of testes) {
  if (!teste) {
    console.log("String vazia: " + teste);
  } else {
    console.log("Não é uma string vazia: " + teste);
  }
}
```

Para, de fato, verificar se `value` é uma *string* vazia, você terá que verificar o tipo da variável, seja utilizando o `typeof`:

```js
const testes = ["", false, null, undefined, NaN, [], 0, "Foo"];

for (let teste of testes) {
  if (typeof teste === "string" && teste.length == 0) {
    console.log("String vazia: " + teste);
  } else {
    console.log("Não é uma string vazia: " + teste);
  }
}
```

Perceba que ao verificar o tipo fica explícito que o desejado é realmente buscar por *strings* vazias, logo, todos os outros valores são válidos.

Ou seja utilizando a comparação rígida, com o operador `===`, uma vez que `==` efetua uma comparação frouxa.

[O que é uma comparação frouxa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215652/5878)

```js
const testes = ["", false, null, undefined, NaN, [], 0, "Foo"];

for (let teste of testes) {
  if (teste === "") {
    console.log("String vazia: " + teste);
  } else {
    console.log("Não é uma string vazia: " + teste);
  }
}
```

Novamente a verificação fica explícita sobre o seu objetivo.

> É muito importante ressaltar que **nulo** é diferente de ***string* vazia**. A [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238965/5878) sobre isso mostra graficamente a diferença.

Comment: (`+1`) Não seria mais semântico verificar `.length == 0` que fazer um cast para _Boolean_? ou seja `if (typeof teste === "string" && teste.length === 0) {`

Comment: @Sergio com certeza seria. Boa observação. Faço a alteração assim que possível.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a class `String` para iniciar uma nova variável deste mesmo tipo, veja:

```
const myText = new String("Hello!");
console.log(myText.length); // Saída: 6 (tipo número)

const emptyText = new String("");
console.log(emptyText.length); // Saída: 0 (tipo número)
```

Você pode verificar a compatibilidade deste recurso no [site da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: Mas a pergunta não é sobre como fazer e sim se prejudica, de alguma forma, o código. Faltou dizer se prejudica ou não e porquê.