# Dúvida sobre modificadores de acesso e polimorfismo

Tags: java, polimorfismo, encapsulamento, sobrescrita

Possuo uma dúvida bem iniciante sobre polimorfismo/modificadores de acesso em Java.

Gostaria de descobrir o porquê de determinado fenômeno ocorrer em meu código. 
Segue exemplo de classes:

Classe `Pai`:

```
public class Pai {
    public void metodo1() { //private dá problema
        System.out.println("Metodo 01 Pai");
    };

    public void metodo2() {
        metodo1();
    }
}
```

Classe que herda a classe anterior:

```
public class Filha extends Pai{

    public Filha() {
    }

    public void metodo1() {
        System.out.println("Metodo 01 Filha");
    }   
}
```

E classe `Main`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String  args[]) {
        Pai instancia = new Filha();
        instancia.metodo2();

    }
}
```

O `println` do `Main` é "`Metodo 01 Filha`". Porém, ao mudar o modificador do `metodo1()` da classe `Pai` para `private`, o retorno do método `main` passa a ser "`Metodo 01 Pai`". Gostaria de entender o porquê dessa mudança ocorrer.

Answer (score 2):

A sobreposição de métodos permite à subclasse substituir alguns dos métodos **que ela vê** na superclasse.

Se o método da superclasse é público ou protegido, então a subclasse o vê, e ao declarar um método com a mesma assinatura ocorrerá a sobreposição. Quando a sobreposição ocorre, ao chamar-se o método da superclasse em uma instância da subclasse, o método chamado será aquele que foi sobreescrito.

Entretanto, quando o método da superclasse é privado, ele é oculto da subclasse, e portanto não ocorre sobreposição, pois a subclasse não o vê. Ocorre apenas de dois métodos terem o mesmo nome mas operando sem relação entre eles. Assim sendo, se o método privado da superclasse for chamado, o método da subclasse **não é invocado**.

Para finalizar, no caso de visibilidade de pacote, a subclasse sobreescreve o método da superclasse apenas se estiver no mesmo pacote.

É recomendado utilizar a anotação `@Override` em métodos da subclasse que tenham como intenção sobreescrever os da superclasse para evitar casos como este. Assim, se a subclasse quer sobreescrever um método da superclasse, mas não consegue, o resultado é um erro de compilação, ao invés de uma confusão que só se manifesta na execução. Isso também mitiga o problema do método da superclasse ser renomeado ou de alguma outra forma ter a sua assinatura alterada deixando quebrado o método da subclasse que deveria sobreescrevê-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Os membros privados da superclasse não podem ser substituídos (ou mesmo observados) pelas classes filhas. Sendo assim, o método que passa a ser considerado é o da subclasse `Filha`.

Somente membros com modificador de acesso `protected` ou `public` podem ser herdados e substituídos pelas subclasses.

Da [**documentação**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2):

> Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by
>   subclasses of that class. Only members of a class that are declared
>   protected or public are inherited by subclasses declared in a package
>   other than the one in which the class is declared.

Como pode observar na [resposta do Victor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254028/41056), deixe a intenção explícita, utilizando a anotação `@Override`:

```
public class Pai {
    public void digaOla() {
        System.out.println("Olá");
    }
}

public class Filha extends Pai {
    @Override
    public void digaOla() {
        System.out.println("Oi");
    }
}
```

Essa anotação serve tanto para o compilador quanto para quem lerá seu código. [Já comentei isso em outras respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236800/41056) aqui no site. Tenha em mente que:

- **Explícito é melhor que implícito.** Deixe seus objetivos claros a quem lê o código. Esse leitor pode ser um colega de trabalho, um
  desconhecido no GitHub e até você daqui a alguns meses tentando
  entender o que está escrito. Leia a [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), é aplicável aqui
  também.
- **Erros de digitação.** Imagine que você queira sobrepor `Object.toString()` e escreva `tostring()`. Sem a anotação tudo vai
  ocorrer bem, mas com a anotação daria um erro de compilação pois não
  existe `Object.tostring()`. Um pior caso seria com o `hashCode()`.

Em linguagens como o C#, é obrigatório denotar a intenção utilizando o modificador [`override`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override).