# Por que existe o termo "Private" em .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, característica-linguagem

Declarando variáveis sem especificar o nível de acesso da variável em C# e Visual Basic .NET acaba tornando a *private*, somente o tipo/local onde ela foi criada pode acessar e/ou modificar a mesma. Só que, também existe a keyword `private`, mas não encontro utilidade nela.

A declaração disso:

```
// C#
string foo = "bar";
// VB
Dim foo As String = "bar"
```

É a mesma coisa disso:

```
// C#
private string foo = "bar";
// VB
Private Dim foo As String = "bar"
```

Por que ela existe e qual a finalidade dessa `private`?

Comment: Tem uma resposta acho que do Maniero no assunto, para C#. Vou procurar

Comment: Essa aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236859/64969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos sitios onde o modificador private é útil explicitamente é quando tem uma propriedade pública só de leitura.

```
public string Nome { get; private set; }
```

Isto permite-lhe atribuir valores à propiedade dentro da classe mas não fora dela.

Answer (score 0):

Além da resposta referênciada pelo @JeffersonQuesado, que já esclarece amplamente o assunto, eu acrescentaria uma resposta sobre uma questão exclusiva que voce propôs.

*Em uma interpretação livre da pergunta:*

> Por que existe o termo `private` se não declarar o modificador de acesso também faz com que o elemento seja privado?

**Facilitadores e convenções do .Net**

Nao é exclusividade de modificador de acesso. Por esta mesma razão, você  não  declara um construtor na sua classe e o compilador "infere" que exista um construtor vazio disponível. Ou ainda um método tem parâmetros opcionais e você não declara na chamada desse método.

Isso tudo deixa o código mais enxuto, sem afetar a sua utilidade. Fazendo com que uma outra pessoa (ou você mesmo) tenha menos dados apresentados para interpretar o código, por exemplo.

**Não é sempre assim**

Nem todos os elementos são privados por padrão, alguns são públicos ou internos ([a documentação da microsoft deixa isso claro](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels)). 
E nem sempre foi assim, nas primeiras versões do [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) `protected` era o modificador de acesso padrão para alguns elementos importantes. E nada garante que isso não mude nas próximas versões. Imagine a bagunça que causou a omissão do `protected` no momento de migrar o sistema para uma nova versão quando classes herdadas deixaram de "enxergar" elementos do seu ancestral...

**Explicitude**

Deixa explicitamente claro qual é a sua intenção com relação a acessibilidade daquele elemento. Pensando em um código estável e evolutivo, se essas convenções mudarem voce terá um trabalho a menos.

Espero que isso ajude.