# Motivos para usar classe privada

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, visibilidade

Quando comecei na área, num curso de POO (Programação Orientada a Objetos) o professor explicava sobre modificadores de acesso...

Lembro-me que neste mesmo dia ele disse que seria possível criar uma classe privada, porém, ele não via um motivo para tal.

Por que é possível declarar **classes** privadas? Consigo usá-las de alguma forma? Se sim, como?

**Obs.:** Pergunto sem intenções de amplitude. Se considerar amplo demais, me dê exemplos por favor...

Comment: Sinto que as respostas para isso serão _primariamente baseadas em opinião_, como a do seu professor naturalista, mas vou participar =)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza? Espera conhecer uns padrões de desenvolvimento que ainda não vi e que possam utilizar dessa forma... Enfim... Vamos que vamos :)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private)

Comment: A questão não deverá ter foco em outras linguagens, somente em C# já visto que já posicionaram como duplicata em C# tem algumas diferenças

Comment: Então @RovannLinhalis, lá é tratado o modificador de acesso. Aqui eu estou perguntando mais sobre o mesmo sobre uma classe. O que é diferente, não?

Comment: É. De fato. É marcada como `java`, mas realmente tudo se aplica ao conceito geral de OO. Especificamente [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89272/78713) acho que diz o que você quer saber.

Comment: Boa @VirgilioNovic, editei. Valeu!

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, na verdade, pelo que entendi, eles discorrem sobre atributos e métodos. Acredito que as classes tem tratamentos diferentes, não? Afinal, como acessá-la? Nem uma classe no mesmo namespace conseguiria utilizá-la... Quer dizer, seria inutilidade?

Comment: Como @DiegoRafaelSouza falou, apesar de ser em java, o conceito de OO é o mesmo... se seu professor só faz pequenos projetos, não deve mesmo fazer diferença pra ele... Mas basicamente você usa o `private` quando quer que aquele recurso (classe, variável, método, etc) só esteja disponível na própria classe. Existem alguns fatores de segurança para se trabalhar assim, (inclusive para proteger o programa do próprio programador rsrs) além de ser muito útil para organização dos códigos / projetos dentro de uma solution muito grande

Comment: Realmente, o conceito de OO é o mesmo. Mas veja, criar uma classe privada é diferente de criar um método ou um atributo privado. Se você criar uma classe privada, quem irá utilizá-la e como? Isso que não entendo...

Comment: você pode criar uma classe dentro de outra... dentro de um controle, dentro de um Form... nesse caso, ela seria restrita a classe Superior. Veja um exemplo bem simples: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9jcmrl

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, agora as coisas começam a fazer mais sentido. Há mais outros exemplos, talvez padrões? Se puder elaborar uma resposta para tal eu agradeço

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, Confesso que achei bem estranho esse conceito, mas realmente funciona...

Comment: assim que chegar em casa, caso não uma resposta que esclareça sua dúvida, tento fazê-la. Mas é bem possível que em breve apareça aqui uma resposta do maniero esclarecendo tudo perfeitamente rsrs

Comment: Valeu Cara. huiahauhau Vamos ver :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Classe privada é bem pouco útil porque ela fica disponível apenas dentro de outra classe, ou seja, só a classe externa pode instanciar um objeto da classe interna que é privada. Nem mesmo retornar um objeto desse tipo para fora da classe é possível porque o tipo não existe fora dela.

Quando o tipo realmente só é útil internamente não tem porque deixar a classe ser acessível de fora. Quanto menor for o escopo menos erros poderá ter em seu código, menos poluição no *namespace* terá, assim fica mais fácil localizar o que deseja.

Há pouco motivo, mas há casos para seu uso. Isso é feito para **esconder detalhes de implementação**. Assim um dia você pode mudar o que desejar sem se preocupar. Tudo que é exposto para fora da classe vira um contrato que você tem que respeitar sob pena de quebrar os códigos existentes.

Um exemplo simplificado e desnecessário neste contexto, só para ilustrar:

```
public class Classe {
    Temp temp = new Temp();
    public string Texto { get => temp.Str; set => temp.Str = value; }
    public int Valor { get => temp.I; set => temp.I = value; }

    private class Temp {
        public string Str { get; set; }
        public int I { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Private.cs).

Você não consegue criar um objeto do tipo `Temp` fora desta classe.

Uma coisa que poucas pessoas sabem é que o padrão da classe é `internal`, ou seja, ela só é acessível dentro do próprio arquivo *assembly* de código. Para deixar a classe acessível para toda aplicação é necessário usar o atributo `public` nela.

Em outras linguagens uma classe interna pode ter outras funções, e se tentar aprender por elas, não estará aprendendo como funciona em C# que é só isso mesmo.

Comment: Eu tentei responder exemplificando a implementação de um Driver para o Banco de Dados. Por exemplo, teríamos uma classe ```Conexao```, e poderíamos ter uma classe privada para implementarmos alguma característica por exemplo um Buffer para armazenar registros e pegar mais registros quando encerrar o Buffer. Esse seria um caso para a tua resposta?

Comment: @lemoce muito provavelmente seria um exemplo válido, claro, dependendo da implementação e necessidade.

Comment: Uma analogia: Um processador tem internamente uma unidade lógica, ela é totalmente privada ao processador, não é possível obtê-la a partir do processador e nem trocá-la (embora talvez encontre algo similar no mercado), mas é possível utilizá-la através de alguma interface do processador. No caso da programação é apenas um encapsulamento lógico.