# Modificador de acesso protected

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

Uma classe comum (que não é subclasse) e não tem nenhuma herança, pode utilizar um atributo `protected` de uma superclasse que possui uma subclasse? Se sim, esse atributo estará visível(sem precisar usar os métodos get e set da superclasse)?

Comment: Se não é subclasse e não tem herança, qual é a superclasse ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre modificadores public, default, protected e private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private)

Comment: Toda classe, no fim das contas, é uma subclasse de `Object`, então - sendo bem chato - tecnicamente sempre há alguma herança envolvida. De qualquer forma, veja se o link acima (a possível duplicata) já tem as informações que você precisa. Caso não tenha, não hesite em [edit] a sua pergunta, explicando porque a outra pergunta não sanou a sua dúvida.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Não. Não se pode falar em herança quando a premissa é de que não haverá herança. Por isso a pergunta sequer faz sentido.

Se houvesse herança aí o campo (não considero correto chamar de atributo, perceba na pergunta como é confuso ter duas coisas usando o termo atributo) estará visível nesta classe que herdou outra e tem um campo com *atributo* `protected` na sua declaração. Não será visível em outro lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode driblar tudo isso, herança e nível de acesso, com *Reflection*. Aí você acessa propriedades e campos `private`, `protected`, o que for. Dificilmente será a melhor maneira de resolver seu problema, mas funciona.

Se você der mais detalhes posso fornecer um exemplo de código.

Answer (score 0):

Há duas coisa que podemos observar nesta sua dúvida:

1. Você querer acessar um campo `protected` de uma classe. Isso é um bad smell de que você está usando esta classe com um propósito diferente para o qual ela foi criada. Uma classe, no cenário perfeito, deve ter somente um propósito e responsabilidade(a famosa Single Responsibility), portanto a sua estratégia pode não ser a melhor.
2. Uma classe com um campo `protected` não ser uma superclasse de nenhuma outra, também é um bad smell indicando que esta classe foi mal planejada na sua criação. Caso contrário, esse campo seria provavelmente seria `private`. Valide o contexto desta classe e a sua utilização no sistema para saber se é este o caso. Se for, uma refatoração é válida, para utiliza-lá da maneira em que você tem em mente.