# Chamando um método

Tags: winforms, classes, método

Olá, gostaria de fazer algo extremamente simples, porém estou com dificuldade de aplicar. Eu fiz a seguinte classe:

```
public class nome
    {

        string aluno = "Olá, eu sou um aluno";
        string aluna = "Olá, eu sou um outro aluno";

    }
```

A partir dela, eu gostaria que um MessageBox mostrasse essas duas mensagens juntas no Form, ou seja, em outro local.

Quando eu chego no Form, eu fico com dúvidas de como chamá-las no MessageBox.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro ponto é que as duas strings não estão com [modificadores de acesso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34/69359), logo são privadas e só serão acessíveis dentro da própria classe.

Aproveitando e mudando o código, porque não faz nenhum sentido uma classe chamada `nome` e dois alunos dentro dela. O código deveria ser assim:

```
public class Aluno
{
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

Agora no `form`, você poderia instânciar seus alunos. Exemplo:

```
Aluno alunoA = new Aluno(){ Nome = "Aluno Exemplo A" };
Aluno alunoB = new Aluno(){ Nome = "Aluno Exemplo B" };
```

Por fim, poderia exibir a mensagem:

```
MessageBox.Show(alunoA.nome,"Aluno");
```

Esse último trecho, tem que estar dentro de algum método ou evento do `form`, um clique de botão por exemplo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Aluno alunoA = new Aluno(){ Nome = "Aluno Exemplo A" };
    Aluno alunoB = new Aluno(){ Nome = "Aluno Exemplo B" };

    MessageBox.Show(alunoA.Nome+"\n"+ alunoB.Nome,"Alunos");
}
```

Comment: Gostei desta resposta. A classe deve descrever uma entidade, por isso `Aluno`, e entidades têm propriedades, por isso `Nome`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, cara. Sua resposta me tirou muitas dúvidas. Valeu mesmo!

Comment: @RafaelVentura se a pergunta te ajudou, marque-a como resposta. Se tiver dúvidas,  acesse o [Tour]