# Como acessar um atributo protegido de um pacote em outro pacote?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, protected

Tenho o pacote animal com dois atributos: nome e classificação.

```
    package heranca;

        public class Animal{
            protected String nome = "Leão";
            protected String tipo= "Mamífero";
    } 
      ...
```

E tenho um outro pacote teste que tenta acessar os atributos do `Animal`:

```
package Teste;

    import heranca.Animal;

    public class main extends Animal{
        public static void main(String[] args){
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.... //como acessar o atributo nome aqui? já tentei criando um novo objeto mas não da certo..
        }
```

Como acesso diretamente o atributo nome ou tipo? Eu sei que o ideal é utilizar um *getter*, mas por motivos didáticos quero acessar diretamente via herança.

Comment: Até onde sei, um atributo `protected` só pode ser acessado pela sua classe, uma sub classe ou pelo **seu** pacote (e não por outro)

Comment: Bom, nas minhas pesquisas eu vi que esse que você citou é o default, já o protected é igual ao default com a vantagem de poder acessar em outro pacote através da herança

Comment: Da uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/) sobre os modificadores e  os links citados, talvez ajude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu conceito está todo errado. Está usando herança onde não deve e de um jeito que não deve. O primeiro aprendizado é que herança é abusada e as pessoas herdam o que não deve, e que [composição fica melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101). E se vai fazer herança veja se está seguindo o [princípio de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101).

Outro problema conceitual é que pacotes nada tem a ver com o problema, circunstancialmente está envolvido outro pacote, mas esta não é a questão.

Este exemplo não deve ter herança e portanto não deve ter um campo ([e não atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)) protegido sendo acessado.

Aí cabe outra questão importante: quase sempre que criar um campo protegido está fazendo algo errado. Ou é detalhe de implementação e deve ser privado, ou é algo que faz parte do contrato e é público. Existem raros casos que deve ser um detalhe de implementação compartilhado pela subclasse, e geralmente ocorre por otimizações.

Existe outro ponto que levanto que é sobre o uso de exemplos artificias. Esse tipo de técnica didática destruiu o entendimento das pessoas em muitos assuntos, e como é abusado em orientação a objeto, quase ninguém aprende OOP corretamente, e causa mais estrago do que benefício.

Esse caso não deveria ter campos protegidos, então é muito ruim como exemplo. Pelo postado estes campos deveriam ser públicos e ponto, problema resolvido. A escolha deles serem protegidos é que está errada.

Se estiver criando, por exemplo uma `Girafa` partindo de `Animal` teria que justificar um campo ser protegido. `Tipo` parece muito errado porque ele já deveria fazer parte da hierarquia. `Nome` talvez faça sentido, mas tenho dúvidas. Porque um animal em específico deveria ter que fazer uso do nome? Talvez, mas acredito que `nome` deveria ser um campo público. Ou se preferir deixá-lo privado e só acessá-lo por métodos públicos, ele ainda seria acessado pela classe herdada.

Uma última coisa que costumo falar sempre: OOP é mais difícil do que parece e se não dominar seu uso, melhor nem usar. E tente fazer de forma mais simples possível, e só usar coisas que pode justificar. Normalmente use o padrão, até que outra visibilidade seja necessária. No seu exemplo se tornou necessário ser público, então mude para ele.

E se estiver aprendendo o mecanismo para ver onde usar, é uma didática ruim. Quando tem um problema procure descobrir qual é o mecanismo adequado. Ou aprender de forma estruturada onde alguém experiente dá o problema e o mecanismo que o soluciona de forma bem pensada. Infelizmente até livros têm falhado nisso quando se trata de OOP, imagina blogs, tutoriais sem compromisso ou vídeos na internet.