# Difrença entre private void, public void, public bool, public string, etc. Alguém me pode explicar isso direitinho?

Tags: c#

Até agora para criar funções em c# era raro usar o `public bool` para criar funções, usava mais o `private void` e o `public void`. Estive a ver um tutorial onde ele usou por exemplo:

```
public bool verificar (string jogador)
{
//código
}
```

Conseguem me explicar as diferenças?

Comment: *Até agora para criar funções em c# era raro usar* se já criou vários códigos imagino que deva saber a diferença entre um `void` e um `bool` certo? Depende do que seu método vai retornar... um método chamado "veriricar" me parece bem retornar um bool, de acordo com a validação ser verdadeira ou fala
sobre private e public, acho que já tem uma resposta sobre isso:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private

Answer (score 5):

Temos que entender o que quer dizer cada partícula da declaração de um método:

```
encapsulamento tipo_de_retorno nome_do_metodo(parâmetros)
```

Explicando cada campo:

> Encapsulamento: Você diz onde esse método poderá ser acessado, para isso você tem `public`, `private`, `protected`, `internal`.

No caso do `public` é acessível por qualquer escopo;

No caso do `private` é acessível apenas dentro do escopo da classe em que foi declarado;

No caso do `protected` é acessível apenas dentro do escopo da classe em que foi declarado e de suas classes filhas;

No caso do `internal` ele é acessível apenas por membros que pertençam ao mesmo pacote assembly.

> Tipo_de_retorno é o que o tipo que o seu método retornará, podendo ser qualquer objeto ou tipo primitivo, seja `bool`, `string`, `int`, `MeuObjeto`, etc.

Esse é o que define que será devolvido pela palavra-chave `return`.

> Nome_do_Metodo é o termo que você utilizou pra designar que o método será chamado.
>
> Parâmetros são os parâmetros que esse método receberá e trabalhará dentro dele

Um exemplo seria:

```
public int soma(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

O método anterior pode ser acessado por qualquer parte do código e seu retorno será um `int` que representa a soma dos parâmetros a e b.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, consegui entender as diferenças

Comment: @GonçaloSousa se essa resposta serve como resposta da sua dúvida, poderia marcá-la como resposta, por favor?